# White noise terms in moving average model

Tags: time-series, moving-average

As many before, I lack the clear intuition behind the Moving Average model. Eventhough I read quite a few threads on CV.

The Moving Average $MA(q)$ model consists of a constant and White Noise terms.

$X_{t}=μ+ε_{t}+θ_{1}ε_{t−1}+⋯+θ_{q}ε_{t−q}$

By definition White noise terms are uncorrelated with zero mean and constant variance. Given that white noise is uncorrelated with respect to past realizations, makes it unpredictable. So why do we bother to include them in the model?

Assuming the DGP follows an $MA(q)$ process:

Why does it make sense to relate white noise terms with eachother ?

How can $ε_{t}$ be White noise if it is by definition related to its past value $ε_{t-1}$? Since:

$X_{t}=ε_{t}+θ_{1}ε_{t−1}$

$ε_{t}=θ_{1}ε_{t−1}-X_{t}$

Comment: Let us assume I have two independent white noise processes $e_t$ and $\epsilon_t$.  I can add them:  $\eta_t = e_t + \epsilon_t$.  Just because I can add them - the realizations are just numbers, after all - doesn't mean they are related to each other (i.e., not independent,) even though I can write $e_t = \eta_t - \epsilon_t$.

Comment: The sum of the two independent white noise does not mean they are related. I understand that. However, why would you bother take some part of a previous White noise $\theta_1\epsilon_{t-1}$ for the estimation of the next time step, knowing that White noise terms are unrelated over time?

Comment: If a hurricane hits Houston, there is going to be an impact on sales at, say, Target.  From a high level, this is a big negative $e_t$ for that week.  Next week, there will be another weekly innovation, $e_{t+1}$, but the effect of the hurricane may not have fully worn off at the week boundary, so there will be some carryover effect on sales from the previous week's innovation.   Not a perfect example, but in the right general direction, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. An (unpredictable) shock may have a longer impact than at one time instance. The $\mu$ is a constant (mean, presumably) and does not vary over time. So basically, an MA process models a single constant (flat horizonal line) with some unpredictable variations (white noise) around, right?

Comment: Right, and the effect of the variations may cross the boundaries dividing continuous time into discrete chunks.  So, if you want to forecast "next week" (to continue my example), having an estimate of this week's innovation is helpful.

Comment: Once again, thanks. I think I get the hang of it now. Is there a particular reason why in practise/real world (or let's say the observations ${y_t}$'s) White noise even exists? I am particularly interested in: why the variance of the innovation terms remains constant as I would expect it to actually vary over time.

Comment: Well, even if it varies, as long as it doesn't vary by much it's probably better just to model it as a constant rather than try to estimate it as a varying term.   As an example, retail demand for bananas is pretty stable over the year, except at Christmas when its lower, but does fluctuate erratically on a week to week basis, at the store level.  We can't predict exactly what it will be next week, so we model that inaccuracy as white noise.  Then we can stock safety stock to cover part of the randomness.

Comment: That is a clear example and makes totally sense! Is it also fair to say that in the case of an AR process we 'know' more about the underlying process (DGP), than for the case of an MA process? Or does that not really matter? For the AR model we know that part of the next observation is explained by the lagged observation(s). In the MA process it is merely a constant and some lagged realized (unpredictable) terms.

Comment: @jbowman If you'd mind to rephrase or copy your comment and post the comment as an answer, then I will mark that answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thanks!  Will do, later.