# Is the white noise a MA or a AR? Or both?

Tags: time-series

I am starting to familiarize with time series concepts, but I find some difficulties when I try to bring the algebraic expressions into a "mental" representation.
In this case, my doubt is simpler: consider that my class did not study ARMA processes yet (I spoiled myself a little, but I preferred to stop then).

Thank you all

Comment: Welcome to CV, GoodDeed. I recommend taking a [brief tour of the section of the help center about what kind of questions fit well here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: I apologize Alexis, I noticed that my question has already an answer, in another thread (though it seems pertinent and "fitting", correct me if I am wrong). Should I delete it?

Comment: No need for an apology! :) The ethos is a collective effort towards curating and editing, more than an author owning a specific question or answer. The idea is that good Qs and As "rise" over time. :) If you copy a link to the existing question with an answer which satisfies you into a new comment here, other close votes might choose to list it as a duplicate and link folks who stumble on this question to that Q+A.

Comment: An indirect, but extremely clear answer to the question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432681/white-noise-terms-in-moving-average-model